# Hataras nedarim judges have to be observant jews?

Tags: nedarim-shevuot, observance

The halacha says that the "judges" for hataras nedarim need to be 3 Jewish males above the age of 13.  However, do they also have to be observant Jews?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I don't really understand your question. If they were not observant (let's say they ate non-Kosher and were mechallelei shabbos), how would you feel about their declaration that your vows are non-existent?

Comment: The rules for the Yamim Noraim Hatarat Nedarim Beit Din are different from those for a standard Beit Din, @Avrohom, for example direct family members (even a man's three sons) may sit on such a Beit Din and absolve each other of their vows. In that context, why isn't this a reasonable question? I happen to agree with your conclusion, but surely there's room to ask